# Lambda Missing authentication token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a simple lambda function to show a QRCode when the link is accessed. I would like it to be public so anyone can access it.

This is the code for the controller:

```
[Route("QRCode")]
[ApiController]
public class QRCodeController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetQRCode()
    {
        //return Ok();
        //byte[] imgData = null;
        //return File(imgData, "image/png");
        QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
        QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode("hello", QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
        Bitmap qrCodeImageBitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
        byte[] imgData;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            qrCodeImageBitMap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            imgData = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return File(imgData, "image/png");
    }

}
```

I published to AWS Lambda and the it can be seen in the Lambda Functions. However, when I try to access it, I get the error: "{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}". This is strange as I don't think I am using any authentication.

[image]

What should I change to make it public? This is where I got the link:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is mostly related to requesting a non-existent URL. Double check what URL are you trying to call.

Sorry for not commenting, just don't have the rep yet :)

Best regards!

EDIT: so it came out that there was no policy attached to the Lambda => it couldn't write to CloudWatch.

Once the permissions were in place, the logs showed that a library which is present in .NET was missing in .NET Core